# Problems with NSString inside viewWillDisappear

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsuserdefaults, viewwillappear

I am battling with this piece of code for days now, I really would appreciate your insight. So here it is...

`fileName` which is declared in my `.h` file as

```
    NSString *fileName;
```

and later as

```
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *fileName;
```

is not accessible inside `viewWillDisappear`. It just shows up as nil object, or some weird value when I debug. When I debug, my console show this msg:

*Printing description of fileName:*
**FileNumber1**

When I reach to `viewWillDisappear` my console shows this:

*Printing description of fileName:*

Yeah, just nothing for fileName.. the value simply disappears.. I just don't know why!!!

**MORE DETAILS**:

Inside my `init` method I do the following and it works fine.

```
    fileName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:(NSString *)CFURLGetString(pdfURL)]; 
    fileName = [[fileName lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    fileName = [fileName stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Throughout the program I can access `fileName` just fine, but inside `viewWillDisappear` I am trying to save to my `standardUserDefaults` by attempting the following:

```
    NSUserDefaults *ud = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] autorelease];
    NSArray *tmp = [NSArray arrayWithArray:someMutableArray];
    [ud setObject:tmp forKey:fileName];    // THE PROBLEM IS HERE WITH fileName AS AKEY
    [ud synchronize];
    [tmp release];
```

At this point `someMutableArray` is accessible, but `fileName` is not. Any insight, thoughts, ideas, will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your init method change it to read self.fileName =

You need to use your property methods so that a copy of the string will be made, currently because you are using the variable rather than the property you are assigning an autoreleased string.  By using self.fileName the string will be copied and will not be autoreleased.

Comment: Craig, thanks so much for your quick answer. It actually did solve the problem I mentioned above. I have other problems now, but not related to this at least :-)