# NSString value nil inside onEnterTransitionDidFinish method

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I guess its a very basic memory concept. But couldn't figure it out what happens with below case. Any insight would be helpful.

This could be similar to [Problems with NSString inside viewWillDisappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952885/problems-with-nsstring-inside-viewwilldisappear)

But I wanted to know why there requires a @property. How can we do it without taking @property. Please provide some inside view.

in .h I have NSString *someString

in .mm (this is my non-ARC cocos2d+box2d game scene)

```
-(id)initWithString:(NSString *)tempString
{
   if(self = [super init])
   {
       someString = [[NSString allo]init];
       someString = tempString;
   }
return self;
}

-(void)onEnterTransitionDidfinish
{
   [super onEnterTransitionDidfinish];
   NSLog("The String is %@",someString);//Becomes nil here
}

-(void)printString
{
    NSLog(@"The String is %@",someString);//This works fine
}
```

Comment: I don't think a method called `allo` exists, or for that matter ever will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using ARC then you need to learn a lot more about memory management.

The following two lines:

```
someString = [[NSString allo]init];
someString = tempString;
```

should be:

```
someString = [tempString copy]; // or [tempString retain];
```

And be sure you call `[someString release]` in your `dealloc` method.

BTW - you are not using a property. `someString` is declared as an instance variable, not a property.